# In ArcGIS Online is it possible to create a feature layer (hosted, view) from a join of a join?

Tags: arcgis-online

In ArcGIS Online I have a feature layer with the following relationships:

parent -> child -> grandchild

I'd like to join all three tables into one (live) feature layer (hosted, view).

The first join, parent -> child, can be saved as a feature layer by checking the option "Create results as hosted feature layer view".

When I try to join this resulting feature layer to the grandchild table however, the same checkbox is greyed out.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible in ArcGIS Online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this is not supported to create view joins that many levels deep.